# Determining if there is a next argument while iterating through the arguments

Tags: shell, sh

While iterating through the arguments, how do you determine if there is a next argument?

The way I tried to approach this was to check if the next argument is not empty but I ran into some problems.

Here in this example I print the value of the current argument and if there is an argument that comes after that then print some message.

**My approach:**

use `$i+1` where `$i+1` will give you the value of the next index.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$@"
do
    echo $i
    if ! [ ${i+1}="" ]; then
        echo "test"
    fi
done

sh test 1 2 3 4 5
```

but that didn't work. I also tried `expr i + 1`, but that didn't work as well.

If anyone could give me a hint on how to approach this problem that would be really appreciated.

Comment: You're in danger of confusing yourself by having `$1` equal to `1` and so on up to `$5` equal to `5`.  You might want to experiment with `sh test 2 4 6 8 10` as a simple alternative; it would show you that `$i` is not an argument number.

Comment: Do you need to know what happens with `sh test abc '' def '' ghi` (which has 5 arguments to the script, of which 2 and 4 are empty strings).  Or are you seeking to determine whether there is another argument after the current one?  By default, the shell will treat references to `$6` as an empty string too.  Some shells have ways of accessing variables by indirection: in Bash, you can use: `x=5; echo ${!x}` and it would echo `ghi` given the invocation shown above.  All shells have `eval`, but that is dangerous to use.  OTOH, it works in 'all' shells: `eval echo \$$x` should also echo `ghi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
  echo $1
  if [ -n "${2+x}" ]; then
    echo another arg follows
  fi
  shift
done
```

```
$ ./test.sh 1 2 3
1
another arg follows
2
another arg follows
3
```

The trick here is that we use `shift` for consuming the argument list instead of iterating over it. The next argument is always `$1`, which we know exists because we only execute the loop if `$#` (the count of the positional arguments, not including `$0`) is positive.  To check whether the argument after that, `$2`, exist, we can use the `${PARAM+WORD}` expansion, which produces nothing if `PARAM` doesn't exist, otherwise produces `WORD`.

Of course, `shift` destroys the argument list. If you don't want that, move things into a function. The following example shows how we can process the same argument list twice by passing a copy into a function in which `shift` locally eats it:

```
#!/bin/sh

func() {
  while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    echo $1
    if [ -n "${2+x}" ]; then
      echo another arg follows
    fi
    shift
  done
}

func "$@"
func "$@"
```

```
$ ./test.sh 1 2 3
1
another arg follows
2
another arg follows
3
1
another arg follows
2
another arg follows
3
```

Comment: Thanks Kaz for the explaination :)

Comment: @user3412839 By the way, if it counts for something, I've never seen a piece of shell code iterate over the positional parameters numerically. (It's done in Awk programs for walking over the fields:  `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { print $i; }`). In shell, `shift` is the idiom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter and check for `$#`:

```
n=1

for i in "$@"; do
   echo "$i"
   if [ $n -eq $# ]; then
      echo "test"
   fi
   n=$(expr $n + 1)
done
```

Comment: You can use `n=$(expr $n + 1)` if you aren't going to use `n=$(($n + 1))` or one of the variants.  The `$((…))` notation is specified by the POSIX specification for the shell.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I didn't know if `((..))` is available in older bourne shell

Comment: It depends on how old your Bourne shell is.  True Bourne shells of, say, 1985 vintage, did not support it.  You can still find similar shells around on systems such as Solaris as `/bin/sh`.  Korn shell, Bash, Dash, and other modern shells generally adhere to the POSIX standard, often with extensions.  If `/bin/sh` is a link to one of those, you may have the `$((…))` notation available.  It varies.  The question is complicated by the absence of tags ([tag:shell] and [tag:sh] are rather open-ended).